# Prove that there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following question that,
Let $A$ be a nonempty set of real numbers with a lower bound. Prove that there exists a sequence  $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $a_n  \in A $ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \inf(A)$.
Adopting solution from the post

For any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $x \in A$ (that depends of $\varepsilon$) for which $x < \inf(A) + \varepsilon$ (why?). Thus, for any $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ there exists $a_n \in A$ such that $$a_n < \inf(A) + \frac1n.$$

Accepting any editing recommendation for this question.

Comment: Let $a_n=\inf(A)$ for all $n$ and you're done. If you want a series then choose $a_1=\inf(A)$ and $a_n=0$ for $n>1$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField How do you ensures that $\inf(A) \in A$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField you are assuming $\inf A\in A.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $x \in A$ (that depends of $\varepsilon$) for which $x < \inf(A) + \varepsilon$ (why?). Thus, for any $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ there exists $a_n \in A$ such that $$a_n < \inf(A) + \frac1n.$$ Can you continue from here?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Comment: @Aziff00, so I get that $a_{}n)$ < inf(A) but how is it equal?

Comment: It is not equal. Write the definition of what is the meaning of $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \inf(A)$, and try to convince yourself of why this is true.